# rand select between n and m

Tags: c++

here is code from programming pearls this code prints random   numbers in decreasing form

```
void randselect(m,n){
pre 0<=m<=n;
poset : m  distinct integers  from 0 ...n-1  printed in decreasing form
 if (m>0) 
 if ( bigrand() %n)<m
 print n-1//here i dont understand print  n-1 what means?printf(n-1) or?i will show code
 randselect(m-1.n-1);
else
 randselect(m,n-1)
```

there is another question :
how print it increasing order? here is code which has bugs

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using std::cout;
using std::printf;
using namespace std;

int bigrand(){  return RAND_MAX*rand()+rand();}

void randselect(int n,int m)
{
  if (m>0)
     if (bigrand()%n<m)
     {
         printf("",n-1);
         randselect(m-1,n-1);
     }
     else{
         randselect(m,n-1);
     }
}
int main()
{
  int m,n;

  cin>>n>>m;
  randselect(n,m);

  return 0;
}
```

please help it does not show me  any output according to main code what is mistake in my code?

Comment: By the way, the title here is misleading.  Your problem here has nothing to do with what you're trying to do.

Comment: By the way, your code contains plenty of other syntax errors.

Comment: Not really a bug, but consider using `cout` rather than `printf` in this instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output problem is `printf("",n-1);`, which doesn't have a format specifier and therefore doesn't do anything with the remaining function values.

Change it to something like `printf("%d\n", n - 1);`, which will print out one integer (`%d`) per line (`\n`).

Answer (score 1):

Your printf is just printing out the empty string. Try `printf("%d", n-1)`